# PHP returns an error about an unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Tags: php, if-statement

I am getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /clientdata/zeus-dynamic-1/i/n/incard.com.au/www/newsite/system/classes/core.php on line 36

and on line 36 I have this code:

```
if($this->postcode => 1000 && $this->postcode =< 1999 || $this->postcode => 2000 && $this->postcode =< 2599 || $this->postcode => 2619 && $this->postcode =< 2898 || $this->postcode => 2921 && $this->postcode =< 2999)
```

I am wondering why this would be, and how to correct it.

Comment: This can be closed under the official close reason of Typo/Not Reproducible: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 3):

You're using `=>`, instead of `>=`, and `=<` instead of `<=`.

Answer (score 0):

=> is reserved for array notation, try >=.